# Uber Driver API invalid scope error when partner.trips parameter added, do not see it available on developer dashboard

Tags: uber-api

My question is how I can access the driver's history using the Uber's API? What I have tried is including the partners.trips scope and tried multiple variations such as scope=partners.trips, partners.trips.content, trips. All have given me an invalid scope error when I try to authenticate.

I have noticed that I do not see partners.trips as an available option in my developer dashboard page [(screenshot of dev dashboard)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLrRA.png). As of now, I see 2 possible problems that I could be having, but I could not find a solution from the documentation or FAQ.

- My formatting or syntax is incorrect when I add scope=partners.trips to my authorization step
- I don't have access to add partners.trips in my default scope and don't have a way to request it from Uber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Access to the Driver API is currently limited. If you are interested in using this API, you can apply for access on the Drivers Product Page." - https://developer.uber.com/docs/drivers/introduction

Comment: I already have access to the Driver API and only the partners.accounts scope is available to me currently, so I am wondering if access to the driver history (partners.trips) is unavailable to the public at this time. Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: Those 3 driver API endpoints (/trips, /me, /payments) are each different scopes. If you have access to partners.accounts (/me), that does not mean that you have access to /trips. You could apply via that link I sent earlier, or if you already have /me, you could reach out via the channel under which you given that access.